# Adding HTML code with Single Quotes inside jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add this HTML/JavaScript code into a jQuery variable. I've managed to insert double quotes by writing is with a backshlash `\"`, however the same tactic didn't work for the single quotes:

```
ajaxData += '<div class=\"menu-item-' + $(this).attr('div') + 'onclick=\"alert('Jquery Function');\"></div>';
```

Specifically, this part `onclick=\"alert('Jquery Function');`

Anyone know how I can go around this?

Comment: Inside single quote why would you escape double code?

Comment: Even if you didn't want PHP solution. We actually wrote for JS version. because your + concatenation is for JS but not for PHP.

Comment: tip: in javascript you use " and ' for strings and in both you can use escaping such \', \", and \n. And in the html attributes the standard says the use of " as string delimiter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See this, its beautiful:

```
ajaxData += '<div class="menu-item-' + $(this).attr('div') + ' onclick="alert(\'Jquery Function\');"></div>';
```

Comment: @Mr.Alien most possibly! Being positive you know :p

Comment: I'm really sorry! I was tired. This is a jquery variable.

Comment: You didn't have to tell its a jQuery variable. Because once its concatenated with + its obviously is JS.

Comment: Thank you! However, the code you posted produces `<div class="menu-item-purple onclick=" function');"="" alert('jquery=""></div>`

Comment: should be okay now. I added a space before onclick attribute.

Comment: Did you add the space there and it came okay?

Answer (score 2):

Dirty escape pheeww...Try this

```
ajaxData += '<div class="menu-item-' + $(this).attr('div') + 'onclick="alert(\'Jquery Function\');"></div>';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ajaxData += '<div class="menu-item-' + $(this).attr('div') + 'onclick="alert('Jquery Function');"></div>';
```

add escape \ for single quotes. if your string is within single quotes then you can use double quotes without escape but if using single quotes within single quote then you have to insert escape character

Comment: Escape the single quote inside alert.

Answer (score 2):

This is are you trying to do?

```
$var = "ajaxData += '<div class=\"menu-item-' + \$(this).attr('div') + '" onclick=\"alert(\'Jquery Function\');\"></div>';"
```